# Create a custom navigationbar renderer to add a custom back button icon in xamarin forms IOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I was successfully able to create a custom renderer in my Xamarin.Forms Android project to add a custom back button icon instead of the native back button. The renderer i used is as follows:

```
public class MyNavigationPageRenderer: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer
  {
    Context _context;

    AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar _toolbar;

    public MyNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }
    public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
    {
      base.OnViewAdded(child);
      if (child.GetType() == typeof(AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar))
      {
        _toolbar = (AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar)child;
        _toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.Navigation_backbutton);
      }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
      base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

      if (_toolbar != null)
      {
        if (_toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
        {
          _toolbar.NavigationIcon = AndroidX.Core.Content.ContextCompat.GetDrawable(_context, Resource.Drawable.Navigation_backbutton);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In Xamarin since we need to have a separate renderer for the Xamarin.IOS project, i need to have the same logic there as well. But since the libraries and classes used are different, i am not sure on how to proceed with it. Any help on how to proceed with the same is appreciated.

Comment: Refer : https://liudeyun.net/xamarin-custom-navbar-icon-text/

Comment: https://github.com/hachi1030-Allen/XamarinCustomNavBar

Answer (score 0):

You could try below method :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
  class MyRenderer : NavigationRenderer
  {
    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

      
        if (this.NavigationBar.TopItem.BackBarButtonItem == null)
        {
            this.NavigationBar.BackIndicatorImage = UIImage.FromFile("xx.png");
            this.NavigationBar.BackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage.FromFile("xx.png");
            this.NavigationBar.TopItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

And [here](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/NavigationBar) is the official sample for customizing UINavigationBar in Xamarin.iOS.You could refer to.